# Will content in a default closed jQuery UI tab still be indexed?

Tags: seo, html, jquery

I have a website that has a lot of traffic coming from alt text in images.  Right now every image is fully visible on each page.  But, I want info, images, and contact as jQuery UI tabs.  The info would be open by default and the images would be closed.  Would any content in a closed jQuery UI tab still be indexed?  Would the images lose any indexing power?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can view the content of those tabs in the source code then it will be indexed by the search engines and will be indexed.